# How to read environment variable in Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, jwt

I am trying to read a environment file through docker compose.

My problem is my code only read the first line of the variable value.

My `test.env`

```
NODE_ENV=development
## Not the actual key ##
RSA_PUBLIC=-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
CIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyRaUPVDIx3e1d/qadcNc
D5TfmAfjCKlTajQPEitF8tNtQKRQc9yZqJjkNwtvctlxmkBmfot5dPqW/nAZhfse
AAY5AKnAPAHrOLrzrGWvXE1NkjuONZq9cTqWludyZp7jH0md1q/D7shZMwL2hEee
gaaM5CWH7nIZ6CASDA9K46NJYyoXw4/sZsUtuuKbUP3W1LlJcaBFIpRRKkv2dEdd
ddqN8yHjkjKNtHi0UtRCjxA6dOuUdMvTiTHiycGwoC6sap0THF4lWHBZb/GXFaeD
adce7iDq5bhbMNT3YfXHlq3MMMJSCJltnVS7DArij/Xf6vF/6chvlI4S9iIZNped
FEEDAAEE
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

My `docker-compose`

```
web:
    build: .   
    env_file:
      - test.env
    //more
```

I was able to read `NODE_ENV` in my `app.js` file with

`console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)`  ==> output `development`

but `console.log(process.env.RSA_PUBLIC)` ==> only output `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`

which is the first line of the key.

and make my jwt token validation failed with

```
PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY failed
```

I am not sure how to fix this. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this might differ by linebreak style of your OS, but I solved this issue by replacing linebreak with **\n**(which makes your key a single line string), and then read it on server by replacing \n with \n

```
process.env.RSA_PUBLIC.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It doesn't seem to do the trick. +1 tho.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

1. How do you store the variable? Do you use  the process.env directly, or something like [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)?
2. Did you try storing without the `"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----"` and `"-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"` lines?

Comment: I use process.env directly. I thought **-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----** and **-----END PUBLIC KEY-----** are required for public key.

Comment: @Jwqq all process.env are essentially text. I personally do not read them this way, but store against a cached variable. You may want to try what I suggested or as a workaround place the Public Key into JSON format and read it from there. It should avoid as well the string problem. Alternatively you can use something like [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache) to store the key as well

Comment: @Jwqq I would certainly first try without the Begin & End Public Key though

Comment: Thanks taking out BEGIN PUBLIC KEY will just read the first line of the key which is just CIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAyRaUPVDIx3e1d/qadcNc. I will look for the cache option too. +1